# Plural/singular naming in methods returning lists

Tags: coding-style, naming-conventions

it seems a trivial point, until you realize that you need consistency. Not being a native English speaker, I prefer to ask both for grammar and for style. Which one must be preferred among these method names, returning a list of URIs, each one associated to an object?

```
objectUriList()
objectsUriList()
objectUrisList()
objectsUrisList()
```

Also, do you consider good style to make explicit that the returned object is a list in the method name. Maybe something like `objectUris()` (or its correct form) would be fine *and* intuitive in any case.

Comment: Why have object on there? It is redundant overall. Is there a reason for it over uriList()? URI <=> object

Comment: yes. I actually have multiple `objects` I provide a routine for. My use of the word `object` in the question is just a placeholder for my real cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would call is objectUriList(), it's just easier to say and essentially correct.  It's clear that it returns a List which is a set of Uris, so you don't really need the plural there.

However, your final suggestion of objectUris() is also good, depending on how easy it is to see that it returns a List in your IDE.

Comment: Ok, not really programming related, but this means that in English you pluralize only the last of a set of chained names. I always forget this rule.

Comment: Being a native English speaker, I have no idea what the rules are, it just sounded right. :)

Comment: Yup, I also go "by sound", but sometimes I have doubts... in particular because in Italian it's different, we pluralize everything.

Answer (score 8):

I am not a native English speaker either. Correct form is either objectUriList or objectUris. Regardless of the number of objects and uris.

Car park = park of cars.
PC storage = storage of PCs.
oak forest
etc.

Answer (score 2):

objectUriList should be the correct answer.
(Unless the function runs on more than one object and then objectsUriList would be preferable).

I like to specify the returned object in the function name but because this is how I worked for my entire life (ever since crappier programming languages). Nowadays, I believe it's not necessary.

Comment: And look the first three answers agree!

Comment: Would agree with this! And many languages (that support generic types), the plural can even be removed and defined: objectUriList<object>

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use `ObjectUriList`.

It is recommended in some circles not to include type names in member/parameter names, so you should drop the List part, but I find that "ObjectUriList" is much more explicit and meaningful than "ObjectUris", especially when you are likely to also have "ObjectUri" as a name nearby.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely go with the `objectUris()` alternative, omitting the "List" suffix. As you say, tidy and intuitive.

Comment: Beg to differ regarding intutiveness. objectUris() could have a return type of string[] or a List<URI>. objectURIList() tells me that the return type is a List<>. But yes, since we all use an IDE of some sort, you may be right after all.

Answer (score 0):

I think to differentiate between Array and List, It's good to append Array with 's' and List with 'list'.

Answer (score 0):

I usually try to go with singular namespaces but sometimes and contextually plural namespaces as well. For e.g. if your return is always plural such as some keywords, I go with plural but if it can be singular often times, I stick to singular naming convention.